# Deploy nodejs+informixDB to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, time-series, informix

I want to deploy nodejs and using informix as my database to heroku, but i just confuse how to do it, i had deployed using postgre and mongodb, both of them have their addons on heroku, but i just cant find one for informixdb,

please help, ty

Comment: We are not Heroku support. Maybe you should ask them?

Answer (score 0):

Deployment of Informix node driver is as simple as installing any other node.js package

```
npm install ifxnjs
```

You can get good collection of information from its home page.
https://openinformix.github.io/IfxNode/
The node.js 10x support is expected to be ready by next week.
The Informix node driver is depended on Informix CSDK; right now you have to manually install the Client-SDK; it is a free download; you can get more information from
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016673